# how to access custom prop_cycle colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've defined a custom color cycler in a text file, and am invoking it via `plt.style.context()`.  The cycle I've defined has 12 colors.  When annotating the plot, if I try to access my custom cycler colors using color strings, `'C0'` through `'C9'` work but `'C10'` throws `ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 'C10'`.  All 12 values are definitely in there. Contents of style file `style.yaml`:

```
axes.prop_cycle : cycler('color', ['332288', 'CC6677', 'DDCC77', '117733', '88CCEE', 'AA4499', '44AA99', '999933', '882255', '661100', '6699CC', 'AA4466'])
```

Test script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.c_[np.zeros(13), np.arange(13)].T
labels = list('abcdefghijklm')

with plt.style.context('style.yaml'):
    # just to prove that the colors are loading correctly:
    cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
    print('{} colors: {}'.format(len(cycle), cycle))
    # now the actual plotting:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(data)
    for ix in range(data.shape[1]):
        ax.text(x=1, y=data[1, ix], s=labels[ix], color='C{}'.format(ix))
```

The result (notwithstanding the `ValueError` that stops it plotting after 10 labels) is that the lines follow my custom cycler colors, but the text labels use the matplotlib default cycler colors (see screenshot).  How can I get the text to appear using the custom cycler colors defined in the external YAML file?

[image: screenshot of example plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can only access the first 10 colors of the colorcycle via the `"CN"`-notation. As matplotlib [states it](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0rc2/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colors-in-default-property-cycle):

> To access these colors outside of the property cycling the notation for colors 'CN', where N takes values 0-9, was added to denote the first 10 colors in mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']

Second, the values of `CN` are not updated within the style context and hence cannot be used for such cases.

However, you can of course use the colors from the cycler directly:
(Note that I'm ignoring the yaml part of the question here.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
data = np.c_[np.zeros(13), np.arange(13)].T
labels = list('abcdefghijklm')

plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = cycler('color', 
                    ['#332288', '#CC6677', '#DDCC77', '#117733', '#88CCEE', '#AA4499', 
                     '#44AA99', '#999933', '#882255', '#661100', '#6699CC', '#AA4466'])

cycle = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data)
for ix in range(data.shape[1]):
    ax.text(x=1, y=data[1, ix], s=labels[ix], color=cycle[ix%len(cycle)])

plt.show()
```

A different method may be to cycle through the cycler with `next`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

data = np.c_[np.zeros(13), np.arange(13)].T
labels = list('abcdefghijklm')

plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = cycler('color', 
                    ['#332288', '#CC6677', '#DDCC77', '#117733', '#88CCEE', '#AA4499', 
                     '#44AA99', '#999933', '#882255', '#661100', '#6699CC', '#AA4466'])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data)

ax.set_prop_cycle(None)
cycler = ax._get_lines.prop_cycler
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None)
for ix in range(data.shape[1]):
    ax.text(x=1, y=data[1, ix], s=labels[ix], color=next(cycler)['color']) 

plt.show()
```

Both codes produce the following plot:

[image]

Comment: thanks; I was looking [in the wrong place](http://matplotlib.org/cycler/) for the documentation of the `Cn` notation.